# Linq List comparing

Tags: c#, linq, generics

Linq is great, but it always seems to confuse me a bit.

This is my latest confusion:

Say I have two `List<String>` objects.  We will call them `sourceList` and `destList`.

I need a way to find the list of strings that are in sourceList and not in destList AND find the list of strings that are in destList and not in SourceList.

This is a bit confusing so here is the example:

```
  sourceList    destList
   Orange    
   Apple          Apple
   Grape          Grape
                  Kiwi
                  Banana
```

So the first result I am looking for would be a list with Orange in it.  The second result would the a list with Kiwi and Banana in it.

Any idea how to do that with Linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just doing this earlier today actually. As sukru said this code should do it for you:

```
List<string> firstResultList = sourceList.Except(destList);
List<string> secondResultList = destList.Except(sourceList);
```

firstResultList will have Orange in it and secondResultList will have Kiwi and Banana.

Answer (score 5):

```
sourceList.Except(destList)
```

Should get a difference of source and dest. You can also do the reverse and combine.

Comment: http://www.hookedonlinq.com/ExceptOperator.ashx is a good example of the Except method.  There is an overload that allows you to create your own comparison function.  Not needed in this case but could be useful other situations.